# Dialog element of primefaces not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-1.2

I am trying to use dialog element of primefaces but it is not working. so I have tried the same code provided in primefaces site. but that code is also not working.

```
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" type="button" />

                <p:commandButton id="modalDialogButton" value="Modal" onclick="PF('dlg2').show();" type="button"/>

                <p:commandButton id="effectsDialogButton" value="Effects" onclick="PF('dlg3').show();" type="button" />
                </h:panelGrid>

                 <p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" appendToBody="false">
                 <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
                    </p:dialog>

                    <p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100" appendToBody="false">
                        <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
                    </p:dialog>

                    <p:dialog header="Effects" widgetVar="dlg3" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="bounce" height="100" appendToBody="false">
                        <h:outputText value="This dialog has nice effects." />
                    </p:dialog>
```

This is the header of my page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Comment: provide full xhtml code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try opening your dialog like so:

```
<p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100" appendToBody="false">
           <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
</p:dialog>

<p:commandButton id="modalDialogButton" value="Modal" onclick="dlg2.show();" type="button" process="@this" update="@none"/>
```

Please post the header of your xhtml file and state what version of PrimeFaces you are using.

The following call:

```
PF('dlg2').show();
```

does not work with Primefaces v3.5 it works 4.0 and up. Version 4.0 supports

```
dlg2.show();
```

and

```
dlg2.hide();
```

but not for long, it will be deprecated in future versions so use `PF('dlg2').show();`

Comment: Yes Kuba....I am using version 3.5....so which version should i use for this to work??

Comment: PF('dlg2').show(); apparently works with 4.0-SNAPSHOT(don't know, haven't tested it yet); dlg2.show() -works with my v3.5.

Comment: You can use any version you want, but be consistent - from what I have seen you are using v3.5 but are working with examples from 4.0 (they can work, but don't have to).

Comment: I found the solution...In the head section this code snippet was required.
      <h:outputScript library="primefaces"       name="jquery/jquery.js" />

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Primefaces comes with own jQuery.

Comment: If you can't see it than the problem lies in your `<h:head>` - this should help [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-override-primefaces-css/)

Answer (score 3):

p:commandButton need to be inside h:form